# Undocumented applescript functions

Tags: applescript

Is it possible for an application to have undocumented applescript functions. Commands that do not appear in the Applescript Editor Library for the application? Is this common? Is there someway to uncover these functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, an application can have undocumented AppleScript functions. These functions will be declared in the application's [Scripting Definition File](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications/SApps_creating_sdef/SAppsCreateSdef.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001979-SW4) (SDEF) file but marked as hidden.

Typically the ability to hide AppleScript functionality is used to hide supported, but now legacy, AppleScripts commands and to hide incomplete commands.